# Creating a horizontal scroll in the iPad (preventing vertical scrolling with Hammer JS library)

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, swipe, hammer.js

I'm trying to prevent vertical scrolling in a page shown inside an app. I'm looking to use Hammer JS, but I'm not sure how should I use it. I've tried several events using event.preventDefault() but it doesn't seem to work.

For example:

```
    $(document).hammer().on('swipeup', 'body',
        function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if using Hammer JS is a requirement for you but I've had success implementing horizontal scrolling (and disabling vertical scrolling) in iOS with iScroll 4 https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll (Examples here: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

When you invoke iScroll, in the options pass hScroll: true and vScroll: false, like so:

```
new iScroll('XYZ', { hScroll: true, vScroll: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work solely with Hammer calls, but adding this should work:

```
$(document).addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}, false);
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't do what I intended. It stops the scroll from working altogether. I want to prevent vertical scroll, but still the horizontal scroll should work (it's a horizontally scrolling page).

Comment: You could manually detect swipe events and then scroll the image yourself. E.g.:   
`    
     Hammer(_canvas, "{drag: false}").on("swipe", function(event) {   
 event.preventDefault();   
 if (event.gesture.direction == "left") MyScroll('left',3);    
 if (event.gesture.direction == "right")  MyScroll('right',3);   
      });   
      _canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {    
   e.preventDefault();    
  }, false);
 `